# Parametric plotting of molecular orbitals

Tags: plotting, special-functions, chemistry

I'm trying to plot a parametric curve, but I only get a blank plot.
I don't usually use mathematica, but my end user needs to be able to do this using that software, so I'm really struggling on syntax

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 - 2*ProductLog[[2*0.003*E]]^(Sqrt*(2*Pi)))*Sin[x]*Cos[y], (2 - 2*ProductLog[[2*0.003*E]]^(Sqrt*(2*Pi)))*Sin[x]*Sin[y], (2 - 2*ProductLog[[2*0.003*E]]^(Sqrt*(2*Pi)))*Cos[x]}, {x, 0.040893729329, 3.10069892426}, {y, ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]], Pi - ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]]}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

c= .003
I'm using this data:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4y5gi8z5d06kr4srwrtkr/SIparametricv2-revisions.docx?dl=0&rlkey=9nw4b7w3lergzt129wva8cpsr

[image: Equations source]
[image: Mathematica Input/Output]

Comment: Capitalization matters (`Sqrt`, `ArcSin`, etc.), and as you've already seen with `ProductLog`, you should be using brackets (`[]`) instead of parentheses (`()`) for functions. It's also a good idea to link to the book/paper/whatever you're referring to when asking questions like these.

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica Code, this will increase the chance of a helpful answer! Mathematica functions usually atrat with a capital letter, change to `Sqrt, Sin, Cos, ArcSin,Pi,...`

Comment: `A[[n]]` indexes `Part` `n` of an expression `A`, such as a vector, list, or array. `A[n]` calls the function `A` on the argument `n`.  For example, `ProductLog[[2*0.003*E]]` should have single brackets instead of double ones.  Bracket astigmatism is one of the pitfalls of *Mathematica*, at least for people like me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of trivial syntax mistakes. Most probably your question will be closed for this reason. Anyway, by correcting them we get a working code.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 - 2*ProductLog[2*0.003*E]^(Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Sin[x]*
   Cos[y], (2 - 2*ProductLog[2*0.003*E]^(Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Sin[x]*
   Sin[y], (2 - 2*ProductLog[2*0.003*E]^(Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Cos[x]}, {x, 
  0.040893729329, 3.10069892426}, {y, ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]], 
  Pi - ArcSin[0.0408823325378/Sin[x]]}]
```